# How do I write setUpClass() and tearDownClass() creating and logging in a user?(Django Rest FrameWork)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have this test case written for two models with local permission_classes, `[IsAdminUser]` and `[IsAuthenticated]` respectively. After running the test cases both the test are failed and according to the exception messages, it is clear that the user is not getting logged in.

````
class PermissionClassesTest(APITestCase):
    
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(PermissionClassesTest, cls).setUpClass()
        print('running before tests')
        cls.user = User.objects.create_user(username='admin', password='qwefghbnm', is_staff= True)
        cls.client = APIClient()
        cls.client.login(username=cls.user.username, password='qwefghbnm')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(PermissionClassesTest,cls).tearDownClass()
        print('running after test')
        
    def test_SalaryDetail_local_permission(self):
        response = self.client.get('/salaryDetails/')
        self.assertEqual(json.dumps(response.data), '{"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."}')

    def test_EmployeeDetail_local_permission(self):
        response = self.client.get('/employeeDetails/')
        self.assertTrue(status.is_success(response.status_code))```
````

Comment: Not sure login function would work in setUpClass. Can you move it to the `setUp` function and try to login there? Also you can use this for login; `self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)`

Comment: with ```setUp()``` the login is working fine and the test as well, but the problem with setUp() is it's called everytime each test runs. I am just learning things and I want to implement the same with ```@classmethod```

Comment: You still use the setUpClass for preparing the data for your test. Moving the authentication to setUp class wouldn't cost much as it doesn't have any effect on db

Answer (score 1):

Django will set `self.client` per default  to an instance of `django.test.client.Client`.
You should make your client available at a different name eg. `cls.api_client = APIClient()`.
Note that if you are setting up data in in `setUpClass()` you are also responsible for removing it again in `tearDownClass()`, for example remove the user you created as Django will not handle this for you.